# Insert Rows with Prefix and Incrementing Number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'd like to insert 300 rows where the Username consists of a prefix followed by an incrementing number from 001-300 (Or just 1-300).

For example: PRC001, PRC002, PRC003, PRC004

How would I do this in a single statement?

EDIT: I'm using SSMS 2016 and Microsoft Azure Database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Insert Into YourTable (SomeID)
Select Top 300 Format(Row_Number() Over (Order By Number),'PRC000') From master..spt_values
```

Another Option would be to create an ad-hoc tally table

```
;with cte0(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
      cteN(N) As (Select Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte0 N1, cte0 N2, cte0 N3) 
Select Top 300 Format(N,'PRC000') From cteN
```

You can use any table (which has more than 300 records) as well

```
Select Top 300 Format(Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null)),'PRC000') From AnyLargerTable
```

The Insert would be

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution! But this will only work with 2012 and higher :-)

Comment: Great answer, but I forgot to mention that I'm using SQL-Azure so I can't reference the master database. Do you know of a workaround specifically for Azure?

Comment: you can create a numbers table in that case

Comment: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/you-require-a-numbers-table.aspx

Comment: @Powellellogram See 3rd option for any table as an ad-hoc tally table

Comment: @tgr Absolutely fair and true comment.  However, when they tag SQL Server it is assumed currently supported versions which are 2012+.

Answer (score -1):

You want to generate those rows and insert them into a table?

Then you can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @i INTEGER
SET @i = 1

WHILE @i <= 300
BEGIN
    PRINT 'PRC' + right('00' + cast(@i AS VARCHAR), 3)

    /* add your insert here... */
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Output:

```
PRC001
PRC002
PRC003
PRC004
PRC005
PRC006
...
PRC298
PRC299
PRC300
```

Comment: This technique will be much slower than the methods John Cappelletti mentioned above.